# How do you block a port on your loopback?

Tags: networking, iptables

I am doing some testing and want to be able to test situations where my database goes down. Its running on the same box as my tests, and it appears that things like the following are not doing the trick

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25262 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 25262 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25262 -i lo -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25262 -s 127.0.0.1 -j DROP
```

I am about to resort to killing my database process, move the file (because my database automatically comes back up on a crash), and let the test continue that way, but that seems like a terrible way to do it.

What is the right way to block a port on loopback?

Comment: Your iptables commands are appending  to the chain. Is there a previous rule that allows all lo traffic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command line command to DROP all loopback traffic (lo0)

```
$ [sudo] iptables -I INPUT --dport 25262 -i lo -j DROP
```

#### Explanation

Because iptables evaluates rules top to bottom and works on on a "first match wins" basis, you need to make sure your `-i lo DROP` rule is `-I` *inserted* to the top rather than `-A`*appended* to the bottom of the rules, so it matches before another rule accepts the loopback traffic, e.g. if your DB was MySQL this rule might also match

```
INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 ACCEPT
```

so if you did command:

```
$ [sudo] iptables -A INPUT --dport 25262 -i lo -j DROP
                  ^^^ Notice the difference
```

your rules would look like this:

```
INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 ACCEPT   ---> this "wins" and request is accepted
INPUT --dport 25262 -i lo -j DROP
```

by running:

```
$ [sudo] iptables -I INPUT --dport 25262 -i lo -j DROP
```

your final rules would look like:

```
INPUT --dport 25262 -i lo -j DROP  ---> this "wins" and request is DROP'ed
INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 ACCEPT 
... all your other rules
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation! That actually did the trick. I need to read the man pages a little closer :/

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the detailed explanation.